# auto-start of linum mode doesn't work

Tags: spacemacs, line-numbers, linum-mode

I'm currently using **spacemacs**.
I have put the line `(global-linum-mode t)` into the `.spacemacs` file but it doesn't work at all. 
It used to work when I used the normal emacs.
I don't have any clue of what is going on. Apparently `emacs --debug-init` doesn't have any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you inserted that? There isn't such a thing in my `.spacemacs` file.

```
   dotspacemacs-line-numbers '(:relative t
                               :disabled-for-modes dired-mode
                                                   doc-view-mode
                                                   markdown-mode
                                                   org-mode
                                                   pdf-view-mode
                                                   text-mode
                                                   nov-mode
                               :size-limit-kb 1000)
```

This is where you configure the line numbers mode in spacemacs, if you still want to do the emacs way, add your expression into `init.el` in the `.emacs.d` folder.